# difference between "/page" and "http://www.domain.com/page"

Tags: url

Assuming all pages uses HTTP protocol in a site. There is any difference in any meaning between these 2 lines?

```
<a href="/page"> my page</a>
```

and

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/page"> my page</a>
```

Obviously I'm saying that both urls points to the same site (the domain for "/page" is www.domain.com)

Thanks!

Comment: Because of your "Assuming all pages use HTTP" precondition, I've deleted my answer. However, I believe it's still noteworthy to mention, so I'll keep it here as a comment: *One difference is that the relative link (the first) one will maintain the protocol (e.g. http, https) that's being used, where the second will always use http, even if the current page was served over https.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. URIs specified as an absolute path are always rooted at the base of the URI space (note that some schemes do not support the concept of a "base" though).

Answer (score 2):

No, not unless domain.com is your site.
Omitting the domain will always have the link point to an internal document.

However,

```
<a href="/page"> my page </a>
```

and

```
<a href="page"> my page </a>
```

can be different. The one with the slash infront will try to get a document starting from the web root.